# How can I solve this second order ODE with Dirac delta

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, probability-distributions, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, dirac-delta

I need to solve the following ODE (a steady state Fokker-Planck/Kolmogorov Forward equation)

\begin{equation}
   \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\left[ax^2f(x)\right] - \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[bxf(x)\right] - c f(x) + c\delta(x-\hat{x}) = 0
\end{equation}

where $x\in(0,\infty)$ and where $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$. The constants $a,b,c$ are all positive and $\hat{x}$ is positive and far away from zero (far enough such that the solution at $x=0$ should be $f(0)=0$). The solution ignoring the Dirac impulse $\delta(x-\hat{x})$ (the solutions where $x \neq \hat{x}$) and imposing that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x) = 0$ is given by

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
c_1 x^{\lambda_1} \quad \text{if}  \ x<\hat{x}\\
c_2 x^{\lambda_2} \quad \text{if}  \ x>\hat{x}.
\end{cases}
$$

This is found by guessing the solution has the shape $Ax^\lambda$ and plugging such guess to the ODE shown above. Doing this we can verify that the solution satisfies the ODE and gives us the expression for $\lambda$.

$$ \lambda = \dfrac{b-3a \pm \sqrt{(b-a)^2+4ac}}{2a} $$

Since I have a Dirac impulse at $x=\hat{x}$, I should be solving for two ODEs, one below $x=\hat{x}$ and another above $x=\hat{x}$. I then have to glue together both solutions at $x=\hat{x}$. This tells us that

$$c_1 = c_2 \hat{x}^{\lambda_2-\lambda_1}.$$

Finally, as we have a Dirac delta at $x=\hat{x}$, we get yet another boundary condition by integrating the ODE around $\hat{x}$.

$$ \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\int_{\hat{x}-\epsilon}^{\hat{x}+\epsilon} \left(\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\left[ax^2f(x)\right] - \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[bxf(x)\right] - c f(x) + c\delta(x-\hat{x}) \right) \text{d}x = 0$$

When we do this, the second and third terms of the ODE drop out (by continuity these two terms must be equal to zero when we integrate them around $\hat{x}$). Thus we end up with the next condition.

$\dfrac{c}{a} + c_2\lambda_2\hat{x}^{\lambda_2+1} = c_1\lambda_1\hat{x}^{\lambda_1+1}$

Putting everything together we get the coefficients $c_1,c_2$

$$ c_1 = \dfrac{c}{a}\dfrac{\hat{x}^{-(1+\lambda_1)}}{(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)}, \ c_2 = \dfrac{c}{a}\dfrac{\hat{x}^{-(1+\lambda_2)}}{(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)},$$

and we use the $\lambda$ that is a negative root for $x > \hat{x}$, (and viceversa for $x<\hat{x}$).

The steps I followed to tackle this question are based on two previous questions I asked here. One case did not have diffusion but had convection (just a first order ODE - [link here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4372962/how-do-i-solve-this-stationary-kolmogorov-forward-equation-with-a-dirac-delta)), whereas the other case had diffusion but no convection (second order ODE without the first derivative term - [link here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4535605/how-to-solve-this-2nd-order-ode-with-dirac-delta)). This case now has diffusion and convection.

The problem I have is that 1) The solution does not match comparisons with numerical results which I know are correct. 2) The solution does not integrate to 1, that is $\int f(x)\text{d}x \neq 1$. I tried to impose this as a boundary condition but once again my results do not make much sense. Where did I make a mistake, or how would you solve this problem?

---

A bit more on the intuition behind the problem. The ODE in question is a steady state Fokker-Planck (or Kolmogorov Forward) Equation. Mass is injected at $x=\hat{x}$ and dissipates both to the left and right of $x=\hat{x}$ because of diffusion. Diffusion is controled by $a$. The result should display a density with mass skewed to the right of $\hat{x}$ since $b>0$. $b$ controls convection. Then, mass anywhere in $x\in(0,\infty)$ is taken out at a rate $c$ and reinjected back to $x=\hat{x}$.

Comment: The solution is, for fixed parameters $a,b,c$, completely determined by the boundary condition of non-divergence at infinity. As far as I can see, you computed this solution correctly. If you want to set a value for the integral over the real line, you need to adapt the parameters

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you. I suspected that it might come to that (that I need to manipulate those parameters such that the integral of the function adds up to one). However I am puzzled that this was not the case in some of the previous examples I linked to my question. In the example with convection only, the restriction is that the reinjection rate is bigger than the drift ($\lambda>a$). In the second case (diffusion only - second order terms) no restrictions were needed. Ill give this further thought! Thanks

Comment: Just integrating the differential equation should give $$0=a(x^2,f'')-b(x,f')-(b+c)(1,f)+c(1,\delta_{\hat x})=(2a-c)(1,f)+c,$$ with $(\phi,f)=\int_{\Bbb R}\phi(x)f(x)dx$, functions vanishing at infinity so that $(\phi,f')=-(\phi',f)$ etc.. Similar formal computations should apply to the other cases.

Comment: Your solution looks correct. There is no reason to expect to be able to 'normalize' the solution, as you have already imposed enough boundary conditions. Are you sure your first equation matches your description of the system? You say that mass is *taken out everywhere at a rate $c$*, but wouldn't this correspond to an inhomogenous term proportional to $c$ and not $c f(x)$?

Comment: @Sal Thank you. Would the Dirac impulse (the last term on the ODE) be the term you are referring to? This is where all the mass is recycled back in to (after being pulled from everywhere at rate $c$).

Comment: @Mattewlab I'm not referring to the $d\delta$ term. I agree this term is a source. What it looks like you're missing is the corresponding sink that *takes mass out* at a uniform rate. So I think your inhomogenous terms should be $-\frac{c}{L}+c\delta(x-\hat{x})$